# Confusion about files in C?

Tags: c, file

I want to work with files in C. I know that the standard library has some functions to help with that. However I have some questions. Are the contents of a file just an array of characters or is it a combination of ints, chars, doubles and more data types. What are files terminated by in C?

A few things jump to mind such as EOF and NULL but I'm not sure.

Comment: They are like arrays of characters, except for not normally being present in memory like actual arrays. *"What are files terminated by in C?"* Nothing. Some functions will give you EOF, but it's not something the file actually contains.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So if I am scanning a file to store it's info in an array or malloc-ed pointer I am in charge of adding a null character?

Comment: If you need one, yes. You don't have to add it if you're not planning to use the contents as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is *extremely* basic in that the contents of a file is just a byte stream until you write code that interprets otherwise.

Keep in mind the very concept of something like an `int` is extremely hazy at best due to [endian issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). While any given C compiler has strong opinions on the form those take, these are *architecture specific* and not portable. Over the decades it has meant anything from [binary coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) values, to "words" of varying sizes, and likely even [stranger things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) along the way.

Files aren't "terminated" by anything in C. They're just files. They have zero or more bytes of data, and possibly [holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) to keep things interesting.

When reading a file you read in either a fixed amount of data, or read until you bump into the "End of File".

Remember, some files may be actively written to, so the EOF position might be constantly changing.

It's also important to keep in mind `NULL` in C means a pointer. When talking about the zero byte used as a string terminator that's often called `NUL` to avoid confusion, a term captured in [ASCII standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), though it actually pre-dates that standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also thanks for telling me about the difference between NULL and NUL, wasn't aware that there was one.